# Rendering video frame to canvas lost some pixel color information

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

Hello all,

I render a frame of video to the canvas and when I do that I noticed next this. I check RGB value before rendering and after and noticed that value is different.

```
<video id="video" width="400" height="300" controls>
    <source src="save.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <button onclick="draw()">Draw</button>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script>

    function draw() {
      const video = document.getElementById('video'),
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = video.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = video.offsetHeight;

        canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.offsetWidth, video.offsetHeight);
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: What was on the canvas before you render the video frame to it. Makes sense that the canvas will change if you draw something new to it.

Comment: Canvas was empty.

Comment: If the canvas was empty then why would you expect the pixels values not to change after you have rendered an image to it?

Comment: You may be understand me incorrectly, another pixels value compared to
video. When I check color in video element I have one result but when I check color in canvas which has this same frame as the video element I have another rgb value.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Reason you have other pixel values if comparing the video original colour to the rendered canvas colour could be many, If you change the scale /rotate, or the rendering position is not at pixel boundary pixels values will be of the nearby filtered pixels, if you have globalAlpha, or globalCompositeOperation value that are not default. Looking at your code it is because you scale the image when you draw it. Use  `canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0)`  and the pixels should be the same, with exception to the caveats above

Comment: And it can also just be colorProfiles. Currently canvas doesn't support ICC, which could be embedded inside an mp4 for example. And even just your [monitor colorProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102828/hex-colors-display-differently-between-chrome-and-safari-on-mac/44124603#44124603) can influence the different results you'd get from e.g an digital colormeter, all this depending on the browser used.

Comment: Ohh, it's -50. I forgot remove. Thx I will be try that.