# The color profile of the Web

Tags: css, canvas, colors, color-profile

If you are familiar with color spaces (ICC profiles), you probably know, that there are "absolute units" of representing the color (XYZ, L*a*b*) and device-specific units (RGB, CMYK ...) which could mean any real color (unless it is specified using the ICC profile).

But on the web, we usually use RGB units (e.g. in CSS or when drawing onto a Canvas) without specifying any color profile. Is it somewhere defined, that the whole web uses the sRGB or some other color space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, and it's not possible to give a one sentence answer to it.

So let's go to [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) :

> All RGB colors are specified in the sRGB color space (see [SRGB]). User agents may vary in the fidelity with which they represent these colors, but using sRGB provides a unambiguous and objectively measurable definition of what the color should be

So this tells that sRGB for CSS `<color>` is expected, with some variants.

**What variants ?**

Well [e.g in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44102828/3702797), the browser has access to the currently used monitor's color-profile, and it will use it to adapt the authored values to match the sRGB output, through this user-set color-profile.
[Firefox has some flags to do the same.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gfx.color_management.enabled)

Note that there is a [feature request](https://www.w3.org/1999/06/WD-css3-iccprof-19990623) to add a `color-profile` CSS rule, in order to allow authors to define the color-profile to be used on the page. Note that this feature-request [has been dropped] in current specs, but may still appear in future versions.

---

This was for CSS `<color>`, but this is not the only place where colors are defined in a web page.

---

Most browser nowadays do read the color-profiles embedded in images, when displayed in an `<img>` element.

But since you tagged your question with **canvas**, one should note that this color-profile info is currently being dropped by the browser when it paints it on the canvas.
Once again, there is a [pending feature request](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/master/CanvasColorSpaceProposal.md) to add more options to the 2DContext. One of these options being the **color-profile**.
Currently, only Chrome is [in the process of implementing it](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5701580166791168), so it's hard to tell what it will be exactly, if any.

---

Also, since we're at it, it should be noted that svg does have a [`<color-profile>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/color-profile) element, and a [`@color-profile`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/color.html#ColorProfileAtRule) CSS rule, which also have been proposed for CSS specs, but got [dropped in the final edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#dropped).

And there might probably also be a note about color-management in videos, but for this, I have no idea who does support it (IIRC it's quite rare, and only allowed in mp4 container).

Comment: @Marian thanks for the edit, but the link was correct. This FR has been dropped by current version of the specs, and that's why it's hosted on an outdated version, but specs themselves link to it there. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#dropped

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I hope the web will stick to sRGB and will never alow using custom color profiles, that are requested. That would be like allowing people use use Kilos and Pounds and 372 other weight units instead of one. All web authors are already able to convert their colors to sRGB before publishing it on the web.

Comment: I do agree, that Color Profiles have no place in the web space. However I've run into a nasty situation where we are adjusting a Mac App where it has GUI colors which ARE being Color Profiled... but the WKWebview content and colors are NOT. This makes the GUI navigation colors entirely 'wrong' visually to every user, always, regardless what color is set on each side. Now, had there been a way to denote the same Color Profile in the web content `<head>` area (or CSS) ... this issue would be resolved as then both sides of the coin would be set to the same Color Profile :( :(

Comment: it may be relevant to some to note you can change the color profile of certain browsers. if you go into `chrome://flags/` and search "color profile" you can select different options. Seemingly, the default option is called "Display P3 D65."

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft and HP sets out the in the 1990's to define the [colour space for the web](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB.html) as sRGB. Since then it seems to have stuck with but minor modification and clarification.

More can be found at [W3C CSS3 color](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#SRGB)

Comment: In particular, [Section 4.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) of the spec says "All RGB colors are specified in the sRGB color space".